# Adding textbox to ion-select ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-select

I am using ion-select to display list of item in dropdown in ionic 2. I am wondering if it is possible to add search textbox on the top of select.

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Gaming</ion-label>
<!-- can I put text box here?? -->
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gaming" multiple="true">
  <ion-option value="nes">NES</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="ps">PlayStation</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="saturn">Sega Saturn</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="snes">SNES</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Would be good to share what you have tried and the error (if any) so to better help you